# can I 'download' to a cloud storage?

Tags: download, cloud-storage

My question might sound weird if this is not possible but just bear with me.

I would like to know if it is possible to download stuff to a cloud storage (generally) like you can to your local storage.

I want to build a small bot that can download media(pdf, vid, audio,...) and send to me. As of now, it downloads the file to my local storage before sending the file. However, when I will host it(I plan to do so on a free service since it's small), I suspect that might not be possible and even if it were the storage for the app itself will be too small to accommodate more than a few files.

As such, I want to use a cloud service of some sort to serve as an intermediate where I can **download** the file, before sending it. But I don't know if that is possible or even makes sense.

After looking around, I have learnt of some cloud-to-cloud services that can directly extract data from a link and store it in my cloud.

However, this is not applicable in my case since some modifications will have to be done to the files before sending. For example, I have some code below that downloads the audio from a youtube video

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

def download(URL: str) -> str:
    yt = YouTube(url)

    video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

    out_file = video.download(output_path="./music")

    base, ext = os.path.splitext(out_file)
    new_file = base + '.mp3'
    os.rename(out_file, new_file)
    return new_file
```

As in this case, I only want to download the audio of the video. So my question is, is it possible for me to download to some cloud storage (the same way I would download to my local storage) ...[ as in `out_file = video.download(output_path="path/to/some/cloud/storage")`

Thanks for helping out! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were dealing with a straight forward file download, then *maybe*. You'd need the cloud storage service to have an API which would let you specify a URL to pull a file from. The specifics would depend on which cloud storage service you were using.

You aren't dealing with a straight forward file download though. You're pulling a stream from YouTube and stitching the pieces together before saving it as a single file.

There's no way to do that sort of manipulation without pulling it down to the machine the program is running on.

It is possible to treat some cloud storage systems as if they were local directories. Either by using software which synchronises a local directory with the cloud (which is pretty standard for the official software) or one which moves files up and down on demand (such as [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)). The latter seems to fit most of your needs, but might have performance issues. That said, both of these are scuppered for you since you intend to use free hosting which wouldn't allow you to install such software.

---

You are going to have the store the files locally.

To avoid running into capacity limits, you can upload them to whatever cloud storage service you are using (via whatever API they provide for that) as soon as they are downloaded … and then delete the local copy.